# How to Dynamically Create Tab in android Depends on Web service Data?

Tags: android, web-services, tabs

I am developing an Restaurant android app in which i need to use Tab bar to display variation of items. I have made simple tabs using http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs. But in my case i have to create tabs depends on web service data. For example data comes from web service like : Starter, Soups, Noodles, Pasta, Sizzlers, juices. Here Six tabse will be created. Here data comes from web service has sub data like Starter has so many verity of startes, In side Soups so many types of soups......data can be updated continuously update to the web service so it is not fix that how many tabs shoud be made it fully dependent on Web service data.
Now I have achieved how to make tabs dynamically with below code.

```
Here result is a ArrayList That contain web service data
for(int i=0; i<results.size();i++){
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
            // Tab for Menu
            TabSpec tab = tabHost.newTabSpec(item_details.getTab().toString());
            tab.setIndicator(itemDetailsrrayList.get(i).getTab(), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.all));
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, BreakfastActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);

            tab.setContent(intent);

            tabHost.addTab(tab);
        }
```

Here i m confused tabs made successfully but in each tab the same Activity will be called --> `BreakfastActivity.java` But i want to display list with different web service data in each tab pressed. For example When Pressed Tab of Soup.    The list of soups should be display, when press Noodles Tab List of Noodles display here(All data comes from web sevices)...etc

MainMenuActivity.java Where i m creating TabHost

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends TabActivity{

    //SOAP WEB SERVICE CREDENTIALS
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xxx.org/";
    private final String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.com/WebServices/ResturantById.asmx?op=getMenu";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xxx.org/getMenu";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "getMenu";

    private Button btn_creat_order, btn_back_main_menu;
    String id;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private SoapObject response = null;
    private Handler messageHandler = null;
    private ArrayList<ItemDetails> results;
    private ItemDetails item_details ;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

        //INITIALIZATION METHOD FOR VIEWS AND COMPONENTS 
        initComs();
        //NETWORKING METHOD
        initControls();

        //BACK BUTTON FOR PREVIOUSE SCREEN
        btn_back_main_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, ViewRestuarantFullActivity.class));
            }
        });

        //BUTTON FOR CREAT ORDER SCREEN
        btn_creat_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, CreateOrderActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    private void initControls()
    {
        try
        {
            CallingDotNetWebServiceUsingSoap();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void CallingDotNetWebServiceUsingSoap()
    {
        try
        {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainMenuActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Loading...");
            new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //MAKING SOAP OBJECT
                        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                        //SEND PARAMETER TO WEB SERVICE
                        request.addProperty("ResturantId", id);

                        //MAKING ENVELOP
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                        //TRUE IF WEB SERVICE MADE IN .NET
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                        //CALL FOR WEB SERVICE
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        //RESPONSE COMING FROM WEB SERVICE
                        response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                        SoapObject soapResult = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(0);
                        for(int i=0;i<soapResult.getPropertyCount();i++)
                        {
                           //SOAP OBJECT FOR PROPERTIES COMES FROM WEB SERVICE
                           SoapObject so = (SoapObject) soapResult.getProperty(i);

                           //fetching properties from web service and store it to item_detal bean class 
                           item_details = new ItemDetails();
                           item_details.setTab(so.getProperty("MenuItem").toString());

                           //-- ArrayList results will keep data 
                           results.add(item_details);
                        }
                        messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }.start();

            messageHandler = new Handler()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
                {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    try{
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        itemDetailsrrayList = results;
                        for(int i=0; i<results.size();i++){

                        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
                        // Tab for Photos
                        TabSpec tab = tabHost.newTabSpec(item_details.getTab().toString());
                        tab.setIndicator(itemDetailsrrayList.get(i).getTab(), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.all));
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, BreakfastActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id", id);

                        tab.setContent(intent);

                        tabHost.addTab(tab);
                    }

                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        Log.v("","Exception : "+e);
                    }
                }
            };  
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static ArrayList<ItemDetails> itemDetailsrrayList;

    //INITIALIZATION OF VIEWS AND COMPONENTS ALSO DATA INITIALIZE WHICH COMES FROM PRECIOUS CALSS IN BUNDLE
    private void initComs(){
        btn_creat_order = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_create_order);
        btn_back_main_menu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_back_main_menu);
        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            id = extras.getString("id");
            results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();
        }
    }
}
```

mainmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/rat01"
  >

  <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#F0F0F0"
  >
  <LinearLayout

          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
  <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_back_main_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btnback"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
  />
  </LinearLayout>
    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Menu List"
              android:textSize="20dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:padding="10dp"
    />
    <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

          <Button 
            android:background="@drawable/btn_create_order"
            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:id="@+id/btn_create_order" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

<TabHost 
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:fillViewport="true"
                          android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
      <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

BreakfastActivity.java

```
public class BreakfastActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<ItemDetails> results;
    private BaseAdapterClassForMainMenu adapter;
    private ListView breakfast_list;
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xxx.org/";
    private final String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.com/WebServices/ResturantById.asmx?op=getMenu";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xxx.org/getMenu";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "getMenu";


    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private SoapObject response = null;
    private Handler messageHandler = null;


    private ItemDetails item_details ;

    Button btn_gmap, btn_back;
    String id;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.breakfast);

        initComs();

        initControls();

    }

    private void initComs(){
        breakfast_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.breakfast_list);
        results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();
//      menuitem_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_main_menu_item);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            id = extras.getString("id");
        }
        Log.v("","chunk to test : "+id);
    }

    private void initControls()
    {
        try
        {
            CallingDotNetWebServiceUsingSoap();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void CallingDotNetWebServiceUsingSoap()
    {
        try
        {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(BreakfastActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Loading...");
            new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                        request.addProperty("ResturantId", id);
//                      request.addProperty("facility", 2);

                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                        Log.v("","Response : "+response);
                        SoapObject soapResult = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(0);
                        for(int i=0;i<soapResult.getPropertyCount();i++)
                        {
                           SoapObject so = (SoapObject) soapResult.getProperty(i);

                           item_details = new ItemDetails();
                           item_details.setMenu_id(so.getProperty("MenuItemId").toString());
                           item_details.setMenu_item(so.getProperty("MenuItem").toString());

                           results.add(item_details);
                        }
                        messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }.start();

            adapter = new BaseAdapterClassForMainMenu(BreakfastActivity.this, results);

            messageHandler = new Handler()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
                {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);

                    breakfast_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            };  
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(BreakfastActivity.this, "OnStart()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
}
```

breakfast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/rat01"
  >

        <ListView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/breakfast_list"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        >
        </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope I explained well. Please help to achieve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a matter of what data you choose to share with the `BreakfastActivity`. At the moment you are sharing the ID though the intent.

```
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
```

You need to share enough information for the activity to show relevant results on the tab. Share the restaurant ID, menu ID (braekfast / lunch), category (soup / juice), and any other information you need to narrow down the result to the list of items. You can retrieve the IDs on the activity using the `Intent`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int resId = intent.getIntExtra(MY_RESTAURANT);
int catId = intent.getIntExtra(MY_CATEGORY);
int menId = intent.getIntExtra(MY_MENU_ID);
```

Search for the items on your DB based on the IDs passed to the activity.

Comment: Thank you for answer Deepak, But i think i ddnt explain well my question. Actually what i want is not that. When Pressed any Tab Same Activity(BreakFastActivity.java) will called here, right ? That mean same list will be displayed for all tabs.

Comment: When Soup tab press only list of soups should be comes and that will be in every tabs.....But right now in when i change the tab now any event occur.

Comment: The same list will not be displayed on all tabs. That is what the intent int extras are for. You read them in the activity and determine what you want to show to the user. If the category is soups, show soups in the activity. If it is juices, show that.

Comment: confused.. :(... Let me be clear...  I am sending id to breakfast activity From MainMenuActivity.java. Here Tabs created in MainMenuActivity.java . Now When any tab pressed the same activity call that BreakfastActivity.java Right ? Now i m making lists here. But i cant understand stell how to change the list when tab change . Actually i cant get which event will be occur when tab changed here ?

Comment: When you set the tabs up, you are passing an Intent to the activity. Intents can contain different data (such as different IDs). These can be accessed individually from different instances of the breakfast activity. One instance of the activity can get ID 1 while another can get ID 2 and so on. You need not write special code to detect when the tabs are switched since the activity will extract the different IDs in `onCreate()` and display the appropriate view.

Comment: If you still need API access to which tab changed, use `tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27687/discussion-between-himanshu-dhakecha-and-deepak-bala)